# ASP.NET ValidateRequest & XML in Standard HTML Forms

Tags: asp.net, xml, post

I have a very basic ASP.NET web site. It has a single page (TestPage.aspx) that I want to be able to launch using a POST request with some XML input. The basic HTML page that launches the request looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="http://webserver/TestPage.aspx" name="Launch" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="XMLmsg" value="<initialize>...</initialize>">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When the TestPage launches, however, I get the easily 'Google-able' "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client" error message.

It seems like the solution would be to put ValidateRequest="false" into my TestPage.aspx file, right? I thought so, too. And the internet told me the same thing. The only problem is...that didn't change anything. I still get the error.

I really need to be able to parse this XML. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally managed to get a solution to my problem, even if it's not perfect.

You can follow [this link](http://forums.asp.net/p/1573263/3969325.aspx#3969325) to a forum post where the whole process is tracked. The gist of it is that even added the necessary attributes didn't stop ASP.NET from validating requests from a standard HTML page, so I had to resort to writing a CGI app to accept the request and parse the inputs before sending back the necessary response.

For information on writing CGI for ASP.NET you can go [here](http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/1143.aspx).

Is it optimal? No.
Is it clean? Not exactly. 
Does it work? Yes.